# c# как хранить время в базе данных

Tags: c#

c#(winforms, sql) пытаюсь сохранить в базе данных время в формате (00:00), как это можно сделать подскажите пожалуйста, использую MaskedTextbox с форматом DateTime.

Comment: есть тип данных time

Comment: @Konst, спасибо !  можно еще один вопрос,  возможно ли сравнение DateTime с time ?  Datetime хранится в формате 00.00.0000 00:00, тоесть мне нужно сравнить и вывести разницу во времени

Comment: можно всегда выполнить преобразование типа с помощью cast/convert

Comment: Какую именно БД используете?

Comment: Не лучше ли вместо `MaskedTextBox` использовать `DateTimePicker`? Задать ему `Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time` и `ShowUpDown = true`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, SQL server

Comment: Что используете для работы с БД: сырой ADO.NET, микро-ОРМ наподобиве Dapper, linq-orm наподобие EF? Покажите примеры кода. P.S. Не пишите в комментариях! Редактируйте вопрос.